# PHP how to loop through assoc array without replicating variables?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, associative-array

This would be easy to do with regular array with a simple for statement. EG:

```
    $b= array('A','B','C');
    $s=sizeof($b);
    for ($i=0; $i <$s ; $i++) $b[$i]='your_face';
    print_r($b);
```

But if I use assoc array, I can't seem any easy way to do it. I could, of course use a foreach loop, but it is actually replicating the $value variables instead of returning a pointer to an actual array entity. EG, this will not work:

```
    $b= array('A'=>'A','B'=>'B','C'=>'C');
    foreach ($b as $v) $v='your_face';
    print_r($b);
```

Of course we could have some stupid idea like this:

```
    $b= array('A'=>'A','B'=>'B','C'=>'C');
    foreach ($b as $k => $v) $b[$k]='your_face';
    print_r($b);
```

But this would be an awkward solution, because it would redundantly recreate $v variables which are never used.

So, what's a better way to loop through an assoc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
foreach(array_keys($b) as $k) {
    $b[$k] = 'your_face';
}

print_r($b);
```

See the following link for an explaination of `array_keys`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Yep, this looks much better. I will accept it as the first answer then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that's what you want, but here goes:

```
foreach(array_keys($b) as $k) $b[$k] = 'your_face';
```